# Sequence of integral functions converges

Tags: real-analysis

$\forall n\geq 1$, Let $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},\forall x\in [0,1],|f_n(x)|\leq 1+\frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$. Define $F_n(x)=\int_0^xf_n(t)\ dt$. Show that there is a subsequence of $\{F_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ that converges pointwise on $[0,1]$.

I have already shown $\forall a\in (0,1)$, there exists a subsequence of $\{F_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ that converges uniformly on $[a,1]$. What should I do next?

Comment: Uniform implies pointwise... no?

Comment: Yes, but it's on $[a,1]$ not $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  a diagonal argument. For each $n$ you have a subsequence that converges uniformly on $(\frac 1 n ,1)$ and so you can construct a  diagonal subsequence which converges at every point. [Note that $F_n(0)=0$].

Comment: Umm, so I first pick a subsequence that converges uniformly on $[1/2,1]$, and pick from it a subsequence that converges uniformly on $[1/3,1]$ and so on. Then pick the diagonal element of all these sequences?

Comment: @FluffySkye Exactly. You got the idea.

Comment: But I don't understand how we end up with poinwise convergence though. Is it because $\forall x\in (0,1]$, far far along down our diagonal sequence it will converge, but 0 is not ok? I don't quite get it.

Comment: A given $x>0$ lies in $(a,1)$ for some $a \in (0,1)$ so we get pointwise convergence but you don't get uniform convergence because no single $a$ works for all $x$.

Comment: So it's like our diagonal sequence uniformly converges on $[a,1],\forall a\in (0,1)$, just can't reach $[0,1]$ right? And that is because we only consider the supreme distance between $F_n$ and it's poinwise limit $F$ on $[a,1]$ but never $[0,1]$, so we can't find an $n_\epsilon$ such that the suprem distance on $[0,1]$ is less than $\epsilon$